# Streamlit : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Tensor'

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision, streamlit

I am working on a style transfer task, my model returns a tensor. recently I was saving that image using torchvision.utils

```
torchvision.utils.save_image(genarated_image, result_path)
```

now I have passed the same image to streamlit.

```
def image_input():
content_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Choose a Content Image", type=["png", "jpg", "jpeg"])
if content_file is not None:
    content = Image.open(content_file)
    content = np.array(content)  # pil to cv
    content = cv2.cvtColor(content, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
else:
    st.warning("Upload an Image OR Untick the Upload Button)")
    st.stop()

WIDTH = st.sidebar.select_slider('QUALITY (May reduce the speed)', list(range(150, 501, 50)), value=200)
content = imutils.resize(content, width=WIDTH)
generated = genarate_image(content)
st.sidebar.image(content, width=300, channels='BGR')
st.image(generated, channels='BGR', clamp=True)
```

But now streamlit giving me this error.

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'Tensor'

is there a way to convert tensor into a "bytes-like object" ?

Comment: You should probably upload the full trace to get meaningful feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved by transforming tonsor to PIL Image.

```
from torchvision import transforms

def trans_tensor_to_pil(tensor_img):
pil_image = transforms.ToPILImage()(tensor_img.squeeze_(0))
return pil_image
```